# Getting no class def found error. Log4J -> Java

Tags: java, log4j

I created a simple web application and added log4J's jar in my lib folder and it seems to work fine. Then i created a Ejb module and did the same thing of adding jar file in my classpath, but i am getting this error :-

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:4929)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4761)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at common.Utils.getRssFeed(Utils.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5243)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5215)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5203)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
        ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:736)
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:626)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 113 more
```

I don't even have any other version of log4j in classpath. Any idea why is this error coming?

Actually first i created a Enterprise application and everything seemed to work fine. But then, i copied files from my enterprise application's ejb module to a separate module and since then these errors are coming. This is in my build-impl.xml :-

```
<target depends="compile" name="library-inclusion-in-archive">
        <copyfiles files="${libs.Log4J.classpath}" todir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="compile" name="library-inclusion-in-manifest">
        <copyfiles files="${libs.Log4J.classpath}" todir="${dist.ear.dir}/lib"/>
        <manifest file="${build.ear.classes.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" mode="update"/>
    </target>
```

Don't know why is this pointing to ear instead of jar. Is there any problem with the above statement? How do i resolve this? I am using Netbeans 6.8

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT :-**

The structure of my ejb module is :-

```
   mymodule.jar
    |_mypackage
    | |_myclass.class
    |
    |_META_INF
    | |_MANIFEST.MF
    | |_persistence.xml
    | |_sun-ejb-jar.xml
    |
    |_log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

The contents of my MANIFEST.MF is :-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1

Created-By: 14.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Class-Path: log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

**There is no application.xml**

**2nd Edit**
If i place lib file in my appserver/lib directory, it works fine. Why can't i make use of external jar files from within my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, it's hard to say from your actual description of the problem (what did you exactly, what is the current structure of your application, what class path are you referring to, etc). But my understanding is that your ear should look like this:

```
myear.ear
|-- lib
|   `-- log4j.jar
|-- META-INF
|   |-- application.xml
|   `-- MANIFEST.MF
|-- mywebapp.war
`-- myejbs.jar
```

And the `MANIFEST.MF` should contain an entry like this:

```
Class-Path: myejbs.jar lib/log4j.jar
```

Double check that you have something similar. If you do, please update your question with the structure of your ear, your `MANIFEST.MF`, your `application.xml`.

---

EJBs don't have an equivalent of `WEB-INF/lib` and while packaging libraries inside an ejb-jar might work with some application server, or not, this is not part of the [JAR specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) and does not comply with Sun's standards regarding [J2EE packaging](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/verified/packaging.html). So to my knowledge, an EJB and the JARs it depends on should be packaged in an EAR.

Comment: Hi Pascal, i am not having Enterprise Application, but instead it's just a simple Ejb Module. Please read my edited post. Waiting for your replies.

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal - You need to package your app as Pascal stated within am EAR file. including your EJB jar files. your EJB jar will get its dependent jars from the EAR. May I suggest runnng your EJB without Log4J, and get that running first.

Comment: Hi Romain, My ejb runs perfectly without Log4J. It's just when i include log4j that i get above error. Why should i package it in EAR? I want my project to be an independent ejb module.